# Django DB migration adds new columns, but do not edit the values already in the table

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-database, django-database-functions

I have a python script for creating the tables and specifying the values that should be added to it. I use the following two commands to do the migration.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This is what happens:

1. When I use the above commands initially (when no tables are there), all the tables are created with correct values in it.
2. After doing the first migration (creating the tables and adding values), if I add a new column to the table in the script, and then run the above commands, the new column is added successfully to the table.
3. However, after doing the first migration (creating the tables and adding values), if I change the values to be added to the table (in the script), and then run the above commands, I get the output "no changes detected". And the values have not been updated either.

How can I achieve third step mentioned above. I am a newbie to Django so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Both the command shows only if you change column name. If you change value inside column than it does not show in terminal.  You can check values inside table via admin log in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked, but the values inside the table have not changed.